# Switching to glTexImage3D from glTexStorage3D

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, opengl-3

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_id);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
               1,             // No mipmaps
               GL_RGBA8,      // Internal format
               width, height, // width,height
               1              // Number of layers
               );
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,                // Mipmap number
                0, 0, 0,          // xoffset, yoffset, zoffset
                width, height, 1, // width, height, depth
                GL_RGBA8,         // format
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
                image);           // pointer to data
```

For testing I only create an array of length 1. I am currently using OpenGL 4.3 but I want to switch back to OpenGL 3.3 which means that I can not use `glTexStorage3D`.

So I tried to switch to `glTexImage3D`

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_id);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             1,                // level
             GL_RGBA8,         // Internal format
             width, height, 1, // width,height,depth
             0,                // border?
             GL_RGBA,         // format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
             0);               // pointer to data
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,                // Mipmap number
                0, 0, 0,          // xoffset, yoffset, zoffset
                width, height, 1, // width, height, depth
                GL_RGBA8,         // format
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
                image);           // pointer to data
```

But it is not working and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Edit: I should probably add that it is working with `glTexStorage3d`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is with the second argument you are using for `glTexImage3D()`:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             1,                // level
             GL_RGBA8,         // Internal format
             width, height, 1, // width,height,depth
             0,                // border?
             GL_RGBA,         // format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
             0);               // pointer to data
```

For `glTexImage3D()`, the argument is named *level*, and is the 0-based **index** of the level you're specifying data for, or just allocating when the last argument is NULL. This is different from the *levels* (note plural) argument of `glTexStorage3D()`, which is the **count** of levels to be allocated.

In fact, the second argument of `glTexImage3D()` directly corresponds to the second argument of `glTexSubImage3D()`, which you're already passing as `0`.

So the correct call simply uses `0` for the second argument:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             0,                // level
             GL_RGBA8,         // Internal format
             width, height, 1, // width,height,depth
             0,                // border?
             GL_RGBA,          // format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
             0);               // pointer to data
```

In addition, I'm surprised that your `glTexSubImage3D()` calls work. `GL_RGBA8` is not valid as the 9th argument. In this case, this is a *format*, and not an *internalFormat*, meaning that it is an unsized format. The value in this case should be `GL_RGBA`:

```
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,                // Mipmap number
                0, 0, 0,          // xoffset, yoffset, zoffset
                width, height, 1, // width, height, depth
                GL_RGBA,          // format
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
                image);           // pointer to data
```