# Switching between glTexImage3D and glTexStorage3D

Tags: c++, opengl

I use a texture array to store texture atlases. For hardware which support OpenGL 4.2 I use the `glTexStorage3D` approach however I would like to use texture arrays pre 4.2 too.

I checked several other threads with the same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237094/switching-to-glteximage3d-from-gltexstorage3d) or [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98591/how-to-use-texturearrays-pre-opengl-4-2). I tried to follow the solutions provided there however the texture array seems to be empty, no texture is visible during rendering.

My `glTexStorage3D` solution which works without any problem:

```
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                1,
                GL_R8,
                2048, 2048,
                100);
```

And the `glTexImage3D` which should be equivalent, however produces no display:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             0,
             GL_R8,
             2048, 2048, 100,
             0,
             GL_RED,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             0);
```

The texture data is uploaded to the specified index with the following snippet (atlas width and height are 2048 and depth is 1):

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, m_arrayTexture);

glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,
                0, 0, m_nextTextureLevel,
                atlas->width, atlas->height, atlas->depth,
                GL_RED,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                atlas->data);
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Uploading the texture data to the array right away is not an option as new textures can be added to the array during execution.

**Edit v2, solution**
As usually the problem was something trivial which I overlooked. I dived into Nazar554's solution and tried to compare it to my code. The problem was that I accidentally set the texture parameters using the wrong constant, so the `glTexParameteri` calls were made with `GL_TEXTURE_2D` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`. After changing these values everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you get any OpenGL errors?

Comment: No, I called `glGetError` after the `glTexImage3D` and `glTexSubImage3D` too and I received no complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at my [Texture.cpp](https://gitlab.com/nazarmx/CGGD/blob/5ed4c4c157e8e73b9b7b102cacde78fecb4c7ded/src/GLWrapper/Texture.cpp) I used in my project.

However I did not use `glTexSubImage()` in fallback case. Instead I uploaded the texture data immediately (you are passing a `0` to preallocate the buffer)

Functions that might be interesting to you: `Texture::loadTexStorageInternal(const std::string& fileName)` and
`bool Texture::loadTexInternal(const std::string& fileName)`

Here is one of them, it handles fallback when `glTexStorage3D` is unavailable. It is quite long because it tries to handle compressed formats/mipmaps.

```
bool Texture::loadTexInternal(const std::string& fileName)
{
      gli::texture Texture = gli::load(fileName);
      if(Texture.empty())
          return 0;

      const gli::gl GL(gli::gl::PROFILE_GL33);
      const gli::gl::format Format = GL.translate(Texture.format(), Texture.swizzles());
      GLenum Target = static_cast<GLenum>(GL.translate(Texture.target()));

      Binder texBinder(*this, Target);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, static_cast<GLint>(Texture.levels() - 1));
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, Format.Swizzles[0]);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, Format.Swizzles[1]);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, Format.Swizzles[2]);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, Format.Swizzles[3]);
      if(Texture.levels() >= 1)
          glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
      else
          glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

      //glm::tvec3<GLsizei> const Extent(Texture.extent());

      for(std::size_t Layer = 0; Layer < Texture.layers(); ++Layer)
      for(std::size_t Level = 0; Level < Texture.levels(); ++Level)
      for(std::size_t Face = 0; Face < Texture.faces(); ++Face)
      {
          GLsizei const LayerGL = static_cast<GLsizei>(Layer);
          glm::tvec3<GLsizei> loopExtent(Texture.extent(Level));
          Target = gli::is_target_cube(Texture.target())
              ? static_cast<GLenum>(static_cast<GLint>(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X) + static_cast<GLint>(Face))
              : Target;

          switch(Texture.target())
          {
          case gli::TARGET_1D:
              if(gli::is_compressed(Texture.format()))
                  glCompressedTexImage1D(
                      Target,
                      static_cast<GLint>(Level),
                      static_cast<GLenum>(static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Internal)),
                      0, loopExtent.x,
                      static_cast<GLsizei>(Texture.size(Level)),
                      Texture.data(Layer, Face, Level));
              else
                  glTexImage1D(
                      Target, static_cast<GLint>(Level),
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Internal),
                      loopExtent.x,
                      0,
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.External), static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Type),
                      Texture.data(Layer, Face, Level));
              break;
          case gli::TARGET_1D_ARRAY:
          case gli::TARGET_2D:
          case gli::TARGET_CUBE:
              if(gli::is_compressed(Texture.format()))
                  glCompressedTexImage2D(
                      Target, static_cast<GLint>(Level),
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Internal),
                      loopExtent.x,
                      Texture.target() == gli::TARGET_1D_ARRAY ? LayerGL : loopExtent.y,
                      0,
                      static_cast<GLsizei>(Texture.size(Level)),
                      Texture.data(Layer, Face, Level));
              else
                  glTexImage2D(
                      Target, static_cast<GLint>(Level),
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Internal),
                      loopExtent.x,
                      Texture.target() == gli::TARGET_1D_ARRAY ? LayerGL : loopExtent.y,
                      0,
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.External), static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Type),
                      Texture.data(Layer, Face, Level));
              break;
          case gli::TARGET_2D_ARRAY:
          case gli::TARGET_3D:
          case gli::TARGET_CUBE_ARRAY:
              if(gli::is_compressed(Texture.format()))
                  glCompressedTexImage3D(
                      Target, static_cast<GLint>(Level),
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Internal),
                      loopExtent.x, loopExtent.y,
                      Texture.target() == gli::TARGET_3D ? loopExtent.z : LayerGL,
                      0,
                      static_cast<GLsizei>(Texture.size(Level)),
                      Texture.data(Layer, Face, Level));
              else
                  glTexImage3D(
                      Target, static_cast<GLint>(Level),
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Internal),
                      loopExtent.x, loopExtent.y,
                      Texture.target() == gli::TARGET_3D ? loopExtent.z : LayerGL,
                      0,
                      static_cast<GLenum>(Format.External), static_cast<GLenum>(Format.Type),
                      Texture.data(Layer, Face, Level));
              break;
          default:
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that uploading the texture data right away is not an option as new atlases can be inserted later during execution.